# Why should Objects.requireNonNull() not be used if com.google.common from Guava is used?

Tags: java, guava

The Javadoc for [Preconditions](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Preconditions.html) from Google's Guava library states that:

> Projects which use `com.google.common` should generally avoid the use of [Objects.requireNonNull(Object)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html?is-external=true#requireNonNull-T-). Instead, use whichever of [checkNotNull(Object)](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Preconditions.html#checkNotNull-T-) or [Verify.verifyNotNull(Object)](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Verify.html#verifyNotNull-T-) is appropriate to the situation. (The same goes for the message-accepting overloads.)

What is the motivation behind this recommendation? I can't find any in the Javadoc.

I mean, they pretty much do the same thing, and in these cases it is typically better to use the standard API (for example, the people behind Joda-Time now recommends people to use `java.time`, pretty much deprecating their own framework).

As an example, these two rows of input validation do the same thing:

```
class PreconditionsExample {
  private String string;

  public PreconditionsExample(String string) {
    this.string = Objects.requireNonNull(string, "string must not be null");
    this.string = Preconditions.checkNotNull(string, "string must not be null");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Guava's version offers a number of overloads that accept a format string and arguments. To quote the [PreconditionsExplained](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/PreconditionsExplained) wiki:

> We preferred rolling our own preconditions checks over e.g. the
>   comparable utilities from Apache Commons for a few reasons. Briefly:
>
> ...
>
> - Simple, varargs "printf-style" exception messages. (This advantage is also why we recommend continuing to use `checkNotNull` over
>     [Objects.requireNonNull](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull(java.lang.Object,java.lang.String)) introduced in JDK 7.)

Comment: Ah, I see! I would have preffered a short mention of this in the Javadocs. I get it, but I guess you could improve your answer even further by adding an example where `Objects.requireNonNull()` does not suffice.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK,

1. For consistency
2. For additional way of doing following,

   `String world = "world"; 
    Preconditions.checkNotNull(string, "Hello %s",world);`

With Objects, you have to use String.format. Moreover, implementation of both the methods is same.